Jakarta validation messages not localizing in Quarkus for custom languages
I'm having a bit of a struggle with translations in my Quarkus app. Trying to get Jakarta validation messages to show up in Azerbaijani, but it's only half working.
What I've done so far:

I've created resources/i18n/validation_az.properties for all my validation messages, including the ones for the standard Jakarta constraints:
validation.unique=artıq mövcuddur
jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message=boş olmamalıdır


Implemented a custom interpolator to handle the localization:


@ApplicationScoped
public class LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator
{

    private final MessageInterpolator defaultInterpolator;

    @Inject
    public LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator()
    {
        this.defaultInterpolator = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator();
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context)
    {
        return interpolate(messageTemplate, context, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale)
    {
        Locale         effectiveLocale  = locale != null ? locale : Locale.getDefault();
        ResourceBundle bundle           = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.validation", effectiveLocale);
        String         localizedMessage = bundle.containsKey(messageTemplate) ? bundle.getString(messageTemplate) : messageTemplate;
        return defaultInterpolator.interpolate(localizedMessage, context, effectiveLocale);
    }
}

Issue:
The weird thing is, my custom constraint messages are showing up in Azerbaijani just fine, but the Jakarta ones are stuck in English.
For example, I get responses like this:

[
    {
        "path": "password",
        "message": "must not be empty"
    },
    {
        "path": "email",
        "message": "artıq mövcuddur"
    }
]

Anyone have any ideas what I might be missing?
Thanks in advance for any help!

What does the debugger say on the following line? java String localizedMessage = bundle.containsKey(messageTemplate) ? bundle.getString(messageTemplate) : messageTemplate;  is bundle the one you expect for the right locale? AZ or is it taking the wrong file?

After some digging found the solution!
Turns out, it was all about the name of that properties file. I renamed validation_az.properties to ValidationMessages_az.properties and moved it straight into the resources folder. Boom! Translations working like a charm.
Why:
Jakarta Bean Validation expects those validation messages to be in ValidationMessages_[language_code].properties. So, by using the right name, Quarkus automatically pulls the translations from that file.
Updated LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator:
@ApplicationScoped
public class LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator
{

    private final MessageInterpolator defaultInterpolator;

    @Inject
    public LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator()
    {
        this.defaultInterpolator = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator();
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context)
    {
        return interpolate(messageTemplate, context, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale)
    {
        Locale         effectiveLocale  = locale != null ? locale : Locale.getDefault();
        ResourceBundle bundle           = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ValidationMessages", effectiveLocale);
        String         localizedMessage = bundle.containsKey(messageTemplate) ? bundle.getString(messageTemplate) : messageTemplate;
        return defaultInterpolator.interpolate(localizedMessage, context, effectiveLocale);
    }
}

also added a LocaleFilter to handle different languages:
@Provider
@RequestScoped
public class LocaleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        List<Locale> acceptableLocales = requestContext.getAcceptableLanguages();
        if (!acceptableLocales.isEmpty())
        {
            Locale.setDefault(acceptableLocales.getFirst());
        }
    }
}

Hopefully, this saves someone from the same hair-pulling hassle :)

Are you sure that you need this code ? What happens when you send the "Accept-Language" header in the request to your REST controller ?

@Serkan removing LocaleBasedMessageInterpolator breaks custom constraint translations, while dropping LocaleFilter causes Accept-Language to be ignored.

With Locale.setDefault() you are setting the default locale on JVM level. You should probably store it in a @RequestScoped bean instead.
